# EpsToPdf package does not work

Tags: eps, shell-escape, epstopdf

I recently run into a problem where on my laptop i can compile a tex file using eps images but on my pc it does not work instead if i try to compile Libre Office is opening and showing the EPS file.

Running Texstudio with miktex on windows 10

This is the log

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Messungen/../../TestflugAuswertung/PosVelA
ccFiltered.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2019-05-04 11:48:27
(epstopdf)                    size: 661425 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Messungen/../../TestflugAuswertung/PosVelA
ccFiltered-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Messungen/../../TestflugAus
wertung/PosVelAccFiltered-eps-converted-to.pdf Messungen/../../TestflugAuswertu
ng/PosVelAccFiltered.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 13.
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=Messungen/../../TestflugAuswertung/PosVelAccFilter
ed-eps-converted-to.pdf Messungen/../../TestflugAuswertung/PosVelAccFiltered.ep
s)...executed (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <Messungen/../../TestflugAuswertung/PosVelA
ccFiltered-eps-converted-to.pdf>.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Messungen/../../TestflugAuswertung/PosVelAccF
iltered-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
```

Comment: Using relative outfile is likely to cause the behaviour you describe since If I were to shoot a loose command to shell ending .eps then if not caught by the correct application my file .eps file handler would catch it by default and open the file with the designated program (e.g. libre office, if that was the "open with" default). The underlying problem is what application on system path should have processed the command so if it should be part o f ghostscript driven by perl then ghostscript and perl need to be early on path and recent MiKTeX does not include perl in the same way as Tex Live

Comment: Putting the file into the same directory actually solved the problem. Thanks. Still what do i have to change in my Path in order to work with relative paths

Comment: in your case you are telling the action to first go down to `Messungen` then up to current then up to parent then down to `TestflugAuswertung` so in effect only need the later part to go from tex folder to at same level the neighbour folder `../TestflugAuswertung/` one possibility is you don't have that Messungen subfolder alongside the tex ?

Comment: I actually did not notice that the logfile relative paths are incorrect. The actual file is like 2 levels above the tex file and not in a neighbour directory. Strange behaviour as it is different in the tex file. But whatsoever i just try to avoid relative paths in future as they always seem to be bit messy. It worked fine by copying files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons to get the dreaded (especially with TeXstudio)

> "Sorry, but epstopdf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains
>   the information

You do not show any related warnings such as

`Package epstopdf Warning: Shell escape feature is not enabled.` so I guess that is not the issue as in [this case.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27779/epstopdf-warning-shell-escape-feature-is-not-enabled?rq=1)

NOTE most recent invocations of epstopdf on a standard TexLive **do not need** -shell-escape however depending on configuration I have sometimes found a need to add and remove it within some mixed MiKTeX configurations.

To ensure it is not a rogue file or "relative" location test your run with .eps in the same folder as .tex (avoid the use of relative folder/../../folder/ whilst testing)

For example we have no idea what /../../ represent they could include spaces etc.

Consider are paths constructed in "odd" fashion or have unusual characteristics (look for spaces Under_scores hy-phens "foreign" characters) many work under everyday circumstances but can misbehave when they are handed from shell application to application. Ensure test files are all lowercase.ext not CamelCase.EPS many work 99%\bUt- nOt_aLl/=\10o^ understandable? For an epstopdf example where **simply a space was the culprit** [see](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483986/using-eps-files-with-texstudio)

A common problem with epstopdf (and others) is it does not behave well with alien drives (do not use drop box or other server folders) If using `\\server\folder`  ensure it is "mapped" to say s:\ or any other natural drive and use that. **Avoid** `\graphicspath{{\\fileserver\TeX files}}` [see](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487402/pdftex-def-error-when-eps-file-is-saved-on-a-network-drive)

Epstopdf is in my experience "fragile" that is it may work on one run then due to poor editor configuration be blocked from succeeding on the next run, again this may be more common in some editors than others and the best test for this is to clear all auxiliary files and run outside the editor using the command line. In windows run **`epstopdf --version`** on its own and check for error messages. Then in the .EPS directory try **`epstopdf --outfile=PosVelAccFiltered-eps-converted-to.pdf PosVelAccFiltered.eps`** to see if the file conversion works to produce a pdf.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. The part of the log i showed contained all epstopdf information there was. More occurences couldn't be found. Shell escape also is activated. It worked though by avoiding the relative path and putting it directly to the tex file. Which makes me wonder why it works on my laptop but not on my pc.

Comment: are the paths truly relative on both without punctuation if /../../ is going up through folders withinin different user names i.e. one with accents or punctuation etc. then they will behave differently hence why sometimes a spaced out path is ok and other times not

Comment: Yesterday I reinstalled Miktex and since then I cannot convert .eps files anymore. These are in the same file as the .tex. However, I get [Sorry, but "MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter" did not succeed.]... I have tried to convert it manually from console as you tell it in your answer but I get this (this is a screenshot of my console): [link](https://imgur.com/p1EwuFD)  Do you know what could be the issue here?